# The ArrayList doesn't show in layout

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to add items to array dynamically and then add these items in array of textviews but the layout doesn't show me any item. I need to know what is wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

```
  TextView[] tt;
  LinearLayout testy;
  List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(99);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    testy=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.testy);
   tt=new TextView[100];
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams dim=new 
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   x.add("hii");
    for(int i=1;i<x.size();i++)
    {
        tt[i]=new TextView(this);
        tt[i].setLayoutParams(dim);
        x.add(i,"hello");
        String data=x.get(i);
        tt[i].setText(data);
       testy.addView(tt[i]);
    }
    setContentView(testy);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only 1 item in your array list (which has an index of 0) but your loop starts at 1 which skips the whole for loop because 1<1 is false

Comment: you mean i have to add all the items of the array before i pass it to the loop ??

Comment: What i meant is to start your index from 0 rather than 1. Also, it is good practice to add all the values to the array list before looping , or having clear ending

Comment: when i looped it from 0 it gave me error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=100; index=100"

Comment: @Lizzy the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is because you are appending to the `ArrayList` while iterating over the `ArrayList`, which results in an infinite loop... until you overflow the range of `tt` by hitting index 100, hence your exception.

Answer (score 0):

`R.layout.activity_test` is a layout file that controls are how to display how to display the display interface of `setContentView` is to set a Activity, this sentence is the sentence and then set the `Activity` using main layout file under `R.layout` layout

remove this

```
setContentView(testy);
```

**Edit**

Try this .

```
TextView[] tt;
LinearLayout testy;
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(100);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    testy = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.testy);
    tt = new TextView[100];
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams dim = new
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        tt[i] = new TextView(this);
        tt[i].setLayoutParams(dim);
        x.add(i, "hello");
        String data = x.get(i);
        tt[i].setText(data);
        testy.addView(tt[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but i don't understand what i should do

Comment: Wht not try it ?

Comment: I want to try it but i don't understand what to do....can u write code ?

Comment: Just remove `setContentView(testy);` in your code .

Comment: gave me that error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=100; index=100"

Comment: You can try my answer .

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for(int i=1;i<x.size();i++)
{
    tt[i]=new TextView(this);
    tt[i].setLayoutParams(dim);
    x.add(i,"hello");
    String data=x.get(i);
    tt[i].setText(data);
   testy.addView(tt[i]);
}
```

By

```
for(int i=0;i<tt.length;i++)
{
    tt[i]=new TextView(this);
    tt[i].setLayoutParams(dim);
    x.add(i,"hello");
    String data=x.get(i);
    tt[i].setText(data);
   testy.addView(tt[i]);
}
```

And

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(99);
```

By

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(100);
```

Comment: when i looped it from 0 it gave me error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=100; index=100"

Comment: change x.size() by tt.length and replace ArrayList<String>(99) by ArrayList<String>(100)